# How to access Rx.Scheduler.immediate through rxjs using SystemJS/Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, import, rxjs

I would like to use the [ImmediateScheduler](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/schedulers/scheduler.md#rxschedulerimmediate) from RxJS in my Angular2 project.

However, in my RxJS installation, this does not exist. I am using "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12" in my package.json which is required by Angular 2.1.2.
When looking in the node_modules/ folder I find a folder 'rxjs' and a folder 'rx'. The ImmediateScheduler is not part of 'rxjs' but of 'rx'. I can find it there in 'rx/dist/rx.lite.js' or even in 'rx/ts/rx/rx-lite.ts' as TypeScript which I am using.

Trying to import it in my TypeScript file like

```
import {Scheduler} from "node_modules/rx/ts/rx-lite";
```

fails. The file itself is found, but the compiler complains that ".../ts/rx-lite.d.ts' is not a module".

How can I get stuff from 'rx' working? Or more specifically get access to `Rx.Scheduler.immediate` (which is the reference to the ImmediateScheduler)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate scheduler does not exist in rxjs5, see https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#schedulers-renamed

> by not passing a scheduler to operators that request it, it defaults to recursive execution

Most times you do not need to add an explicit scheduler and let Rx figure it out by itself.

Comment: Thanks. However, the problem we had with schedulers was that execution was not immediate even though we did not specify any specific schedulers. Actually when thinking about it - I think what made it asynchronous was the Angular2 HTTP call inside the observable.